# How to prevent user enumeration using WordPress forgot password form?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-hook, wordpress-login

It's possible to enumerate a list of WordPress users by using the "forgot password" form. If you enter a username/email that DOESN'T exist, you receive an error telling you as much. And if you enter a username/email that DOES exist, it will confirm that fact with a success message:

[image: Password reset request success message.]

I'd like to have this form return the same message either way, but I can't seem to find the right WordPress hooks to do this. Has anyone tackled this before or have any suggestions on how to obfuscate the response?

Comment: I have not tackled this precise issue before, but could you be more specific about what you're trying to achieve? What would "returning the same message either way" mean, since in one case you're generating a confirmation link, and in the other you're getting an error message or messages indicating the username or email doesn't exist and inviting you to try again.

Comment: @CKMacLeod the response simply wouldn't return an error. It could easily just say 'A blah blah link has been sent to the email requested'

Comment: But, possibly see this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115539/custom-login-errors-and-variables-i-can-use

Comment: @CKMacLeod I'd like the response to a password reset request to be generic and - as Tim Hallman suggests - exactly the same whether an error was encountered or not. The main problem is that when a successful request is made, the reset request form disappears, indicating that the user does in fact exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
// Lost password: same behaviour if account found or not
add_filter( 'lostpassword_errors', 'lostpassword_errors_custom', 20, 3 );
function lostpassword_errors_custom ($errors, $user_data) {
    // User not found in general = $user_data is empty (= false)
    // User not found from email = error is "invalid_email"
    // User not found from login = no error (+  $user_data is empty)
    // Let other errors occur
    // Otherwise use the following commented IF instead = always redirect, for example even if form submitted with empty data
    //if (!$user_data)) {
    if ($errors->get_error_code() === 'invalid_email' || (!$errors->has_errors() && !$user_data)) {
        wp_safe_redirect( 'wp-login.php?checkemail=confirm' );
        exit;
    }
    return $errors;
}
```